# What's the URL to my uploaded file?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to publicly access an uploaded file but can't figure out what the URL would be? I know it's a stupid question but I can't seem to figure this out.

Heres my code for saving the file, I can see it being stored in the storage folder so the upload seems OK!

```
$path = Storage::putFile('apps/icons', $request->file('app_icon'), 'public');
```

`dd(Storage::url($path));` gives me a path but when visiting it in the browser I only get the laravel default 404 page...

Comment: Have you give permission to the folder where you upload files?

Comment: @DsRaj I did chmod -R 777 on /public and /storage... still can't se the uploaded files though.. how can I figure out the URL?